# PySpark and MongoDB Connector: Cannot query with dates inside a pipeline

Tags: mongodb, datetime, pyspark, aggregation-framework

I'm running PySpark and I have set up a MongoDB connector to get access to my database. I'm trying to build a pipeline where the $match stage includes filtering upon dates. I cannot make this work and I might need something like ISODATE("") here.

I have already tried the datetime objects with the correct formats and I also tried to pass isoformat string in the $match stage. None of these worked.

```
mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost/databaseName.collection"
my_spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongoURI).getOrCreate()
from_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
to_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
products =['P1', 'P2']
clients = ['C1', 'C2']
pipeline = [
 {'$match': {'$and': [ { '_created_at': { '$gt': from_date } }, { '_created_at': { '$lt': to_date } } ],'product': {'$in': products},'client': {'$in':clients }}},
 {'$project': {'product': 1,'client': 1}}]
df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("pipeline", pipeline).load()
print(df.printSchema())
```

I'm expecting to get some documents back, but I get this error instead

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid Aggregation map Map ... 
 It should be a list of pipeline stages (Documents) or a single pipeline stage (Document)
```

If I pass the dates as string I get a None schema and when I exclude the date-based part of the query, I get documents back. So, it's that part that has the issue.

Comment: I have found a solution. Actually, it was pretty simple. I have just to define the date as follows: from_date = str(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1).isoformat()) + "Z" and then inside the pipeline { '_created_at': { '$gt': { '$date': from_date} } }

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the dates in your case its from_date and to_date as your passing them in a form of variable to pipeline, PySpark doesn't take the format you have defined for ISO dates. Thats the reason why it fails, but the error is not much self explanatory.

Below is a fix by converting the dates to ISO dates and then passing to pipeline:

```
 from_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
 print(type(from_date ))
 >> <type 'datetime.datetime'>
 from_date = from_date.isoformat()
 from_date = from_date+"Z"
 print(from_date)
 >> 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

This is how your conversion should be done and then pass the variable to pipeline

```
pipeline = [{'$match': {'$and': [ { '_created_at': { '$gt': from_date } }, { '_created_at': { '$lt': to_date } } ],'product': {'$in': products},'client': {'$in':clients }}},{'$project': {'product': 1,'client': 1}}]
```